# How to add text to a line in Altair?

Tags: python, pandas, altair

I would like to add text to these reference lines, following is the code I used:

```
double2 = alt.Chart(source2).mark_line().transform_calculate(
    double2='5*pow(2,(datum.x/2))'
).transform_fold(
    ['double2']
).encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y=alt.Y('value:Q', scale=alt.Scale(type='log')),
    color=alt.value('lightgray')
)

source5 = alt.sequence(start=0, stop=28, step=1, as_='x')

double5 = alt.Chart(source5).mark_line().transform_calculate(
    double5='5*pow(2,(datum.x/5))'
).transform_fold(
    ['double5']
).encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y='value:Q',
    color=alt.value('lightgray')
)

double2 + double5
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4qtn.png)

I would like to add the text along those lines "deaths double every 2 days" and "every 5 days", like in the chart from Our World in Data below:

[our world in data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GC1M.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not any good automated way to do this, because text angles in Vega-Lite cannot be tied to data coordinates. But with a bit of tweaking you can accomplish this with a text layer:

```
import altair as alt

source2 = alt.sequence(start=0, stop=28, step=1, as_='x')

double2 = alt.Chart(source2).mark_line().transform_calculate(
    double2='5*pow(2,(datum.x/2))'
).transform_fold(
    ['double2']
).encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y=alt.Y('value:Q', scale=alt.Scale(type='log')),
    color=alt.value('lightgray')
)

source5 = alt.sequence(start=0, stop=28, step=1, as_='x')

double5 = alt.Chart(source5).mark_line().transform_calculate(
    double5='5*pow(2,(datum.x/5))'
).transform_fold(
    ['double5']
).encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y='value:Q',
    color=alt.value('lightgray')
)

text5 = alt.Chart({'values':[{'x': 20, 'y': 100}]}).mark_text(
    text='doubles every 5 days', angle=346
).encode(
    x='x:Q', y='y:Q'
)

text2 = alt.Chart({'values':[{'x': 20, 'y': 7000}]}).mark_text(
    text='doubles every 2 days', angle=327
).encode(
    x='x:Q', y='y:Q'
)

double2 + double5 + text2 + text5
```

[image]

This will be a bit cleaner in Altair 4.2, once it supports the new datum encoding.

Comment: Thanks so much @jakevdp !!! It is just annoying to have to tweak it all the time. But this works for now, I hope when I update the chart I won't need to do much tweaking. Thanks once again!